# HOW to determine $S$ in $SEIR$ epidemiology model

Tags: fitting, epidemiology, integral, analytical

With the contact rate parameters for a $SEIR$ model as follows:

$$
\begin{aligned}
\beta &= 0.139\\
\gamma &= \frac{1}{10.4}\\
\sigma &= 0.1\\
R_0 &= 1.4456\\
N &= 3,787,000\\
I(0) &= 35
\end{aligned}
$$

How can we calculate the analystical value for $S$ at $t = 280$(days) in an $SEIR$ model?

Comment: **1:** You can compute this numerically or analytically by solving the related differential equation for the model. **2:** With a large population, like more than 3.7 million, the SEIR model is not realistic because it is a compartment model that assumes a homogeneous distribution of the spread (meaning that location does not matter and anybody of the 3.7 million is equally likely to be infected).